# How to identify a file encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure out the encoding of a text file. I did try a lot of the common ones (with Notepad++), but I've failed so far.

---

**A few hints**: The file was originally an Eudora mbx file, with mostly French content. It dates from around 1998, and might have come from the MacOS version of Eudora. Non-ASCII are encoded as single-byte:

- 0x82 is â
- 0x87 is à
- 0xc1 is ç
- 0xc8 is é
- 0xcb is è
- 0xcd is ê

Line feeds are encoded as 0x0d 0x0a.

I could search/replace them all, but…

---

**Edit**: To answer the questions in the comments:

- `file--mime-encoding` reports `unknown-8bit`, `file --mime-type` reports `text/plain`, `file` reports `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines (370), with CRLF line terminators`.
- There is no file header - the beginning of the file is the beginning of the text (`From ???@???`, which is the standard email header in Eudora mbx files).
- I'm able to test on MacOS 14.x, MacOS 7.6.1 (on BasiliskII), Debian 12.4, Windows 10 and Windows XP. None of those use the correct character set by default.

---

**Another edit** : looking more carefully, this file contain roughly 300 emails one after the other, and they use at least two different encodings, which explain the discrepancies.
Here's my current guess at the whole set, but I probably can't just search and replace across the whole thing.

```
81 '°' (degree)
82 'â'
83 'ü'
84 'ã'
85 'É'
86 '"'
87 'à'
88 'ö'
89 'ä'
90 '•'
92 '''
97     Line feed ?
9a 'ß'
a0 ' ' (non-breakable?)
aa '”' (balancing with b4)
ab 'Ç'
b0 '°'
b1 '~'
b4 '“" (balancing with aa)
b7 'á'
b8 'ü'
bb 'é' 'È'
bc 'ù'
bf 'À'
c0 'À'
c1 'ç'
c8 'é'
c9 'É'
cb 'è'
cc 'í'
cd 'ê'
d0 'õ'
d3 'î'
d4 'ï'
d7 'û'
d9 'ô'
db 'ó'
dd 'ú'
e0 'à'
e2 'â'
e7 'ç'
e8 'è'
e9 'é'
ea 'ê'
ed '''
ee 'î'
ef 'ï'
f4 'ô'
f9 'ù'
fb 'û'
fc 'ü'
fe '''
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski They mention Notepad++ so it would seem to be Windows.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Some people use Notepad++ on Wine

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The OS shall be stated explicitly nevertheless. This information shall come from the asker, not from our guesswork.

Comment: What are the first few bytes of the file in hexadecimal ? This is in many cases the file's signature. See Wikipedia [List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Comment: In my Debian 12 `iconv` 2.36 knows 1180 encodings (although some names may be aliases, I think). I wrote a script that takes the output of `printf '\x82\x87\xc1\xc8\xcb\xcd\x0d\x0a'` and converts it to UTF-8 by assuming each encoding, one after another. No output even resembles `âàçéèê`. As a sanity check I encoded `Żółć` in ISO_8859-2, created a corresponding `printf` command and let the script test it. I got `Żółć` from several encodings (including ISO_8859-2, as expected) plus similar strings from several other. It seems the encoding in question is not even close to anything `iconv` knows.

Comment: Did you try converting the files using `unix2dos` or the oppositely named `dos2unix`? Those are common utilities on Linux systems and can be installed via Homebrew on macOS.

Comment: Thanks  @KamilMaciorowski. I'm starting to wonder if the file was somehow double-converted between encodings, at which point it becomes some kind of crypto challenge. I've started writing my own translator.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: thanks for the hint - I didn't know that those could do more than linefeed conversions. But without knowing the encoding to use, it's as random as what I did with Notepad++ earlier.

Comment: Some characters match when I do `<mystery_file iconv -c -f WINDOWS-1252 -t MAC | iconv -c -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8`. Other characters match upon `<mystery_file iconv -c -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8`. Maybe the original encoding was `MAC` (note the final `UTF-8` in my commands is only because Linux expects it; the original encoding could be anything), converted to `WINDOWS-1252`, edited as if it was `MAC` (i.e. some text using `MAC` encoding was added or appended) and converted from `MAC` to `WINDOWS-1252` again.

Comment: "roughly 300 emails one after the other, and they use at least two different encodings" – If I'm right then some of them will look fine if you open the file as `WINDOWS-1252` (or convert from `WINDOWS-1252` to whatever encoding you need). Others will look right if you convert from `WINDOWS-1252` to `MAC` and *then* open as `WINDOWS-1252` (or convert from `WINDOWS-1252` to whatever encoding you need).

Comment: A.M.A.Z.I.N.G. That's it. I may have to fine-tune between Windows-1252, latin1 and the other similars, but you got the core idea. And I can run the conversion on the whole file and pick the right chunks with TortoiseMerge or something similar. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it. THANKS!

Comment: Nah. The question is "how to identify a file encoding in Windows?". What I did was some shell scripting, guessing, bruteforcing, optimizing and being lucky in Linux. My comments state what the encoding is, not how to identify it. I could describe the method I used, still it's in Linux. I have absolutely no idea how to identify a file encoding in Windows. Even if you change the question, I cannot see how I could answer for future users with similar problems. There was too much luck, hunch, trial and error to even call my method a procedure.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for pointing that out. "in Windows" was added to the title by someone else - I just reverted it. My question was really about the encoding of this specific file. Even if you can't write it as a procedure, documenting that sometimes, double-encoding and/or reverse encoding are possible might give the insights that someone else needs. In any case: thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Install Python (e.g. from the Microsoft Store), then `pip install chardet`, then you should have either the `chardetect` command or at least `python -m chardet`. It will perform statistical analysis to guess at the most likely charsets.

```
python -m chardet somefile.txt
```

> A few hints: The file was originally an Eudora mbx file, with mostly French content. It dates from around 1998, and might have come from the MacOS version of Eudora. Non-ASCII are encoded as single-byte:

Then it might not *have* a single encoding; it's probably a mix of messages in a few different encodings. You need to perform charset detection for each message separately.

Comment: It indeeds has more than one, including some applied "in reverse". Thanks for chiming in.